# jQuery Conflicts With Joomla YooTheme WidgetKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I am developing a Joomla site for a customer locally at the moment.

I have a jQuery conflict which is doing my head in!

I am running this template from YooTheme:
http://www.yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2013/infinite/

The top slideshow is jQuery controlled. It is run by YooThemes "WidgetKit".

I have a simple contact form which is validated using jQuery (for email address etc).

When ever i put the contact form onto the site, the top slideshow disappears.

This is the jQuery code:

```
<script src="********/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();

function isInt(n) {
return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}

// Form validation
jQuery(".darkBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var email = jQuery("form.form_contact .email").val();

var zipCheck = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i;
var zip = jQuery("form.form_contact .zipcode").val();

var phoneCheck = /^\d+$/;
var phone = jQuery("form.form_contact .phone").val();

var error = "";

if(!email_check.test(email))
{
error = "Please give a valid email address."

}

if(!zipCheck.test(zip))
{
error = "Please give a valid postcode.";
}

if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || phone.length != 11)
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}


// No error ? -> Submit
if(error == "")
{
jQuery(".form_error").hide();
jQuery("form#contact_form").submit();
} else {
jQuery(".form_error").empty().text(error);
jQuery(".form_error").show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

A Friend of mine who knows very basic jQuery knocked this up for me. However, he does not know enough to solve the problem. I have no idea when it comes to jQuery.

I done a bit of reading and found somewhere which said try changing the "$" to "jQuery" in the code which is why it has "jQuery" instead of the "$" sign.

How can i get these both to work together?
Any help is appreciated.

New Code as requested in comments below:

```
<script src="********/js/$.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function($) {


function isInt(n) {
return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}

// Form validation
$(".darkBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var email = $("form.form_contact .email").val();

var zipCheck = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i;
var zip = $("form.form_contact .zipcode").val();

var phoneCheck = /^\d+$/;
var phone = $("form.form_contact .phone").val();

var error = "";

if(!email_check.test(email))
{
error = "Please give a valid email address."

}

if(!zipCheck.test(zip))
{
error = "Please give a valid postcode.";
}

if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || phone.length != 11)
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}


// No error ? -> Submit
if(error == "")
{
$(".form_error").hide();
$("form#contact_form").submit();
} else {
$(".form_error").empty().text(error);
$(".form_error").show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Use `jQuery.noConflict();` as soon as you can (not **inside** the `$(document).ready`) handler. From there, you can use `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { });`, and inside of the handler, you can use `$` to refer to jQuery still

Comment: hello, do i need to add that $ inside the (function () {});?

Comment: That will allow you to use `$` **instead of** `jQuery` **inside** the handler

Comment: No luck unfortunately mate - still the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that it would solve the problem, just help reduce text because you could refer to the jQuery library with `$` instead of `jQuery`. Did you place `jQuery.noConflict();` **outside** of any other code? In your code, it's **inside** of the handler. Did you try putting it **before** the handler declaration?

Comment: @Dr.Pepper `jQuery.noConflict();` Should come directly after you include the jQuery library onto the page.

Comment: Added to Original post

Comment: @Dr.Pepper I'm guessing you used search and replace because you accidentally replaced your jQuery url with $

Comment: Ah, forgot to tick the box "only in selection" - what a muppet. Let me try again! lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `jQuery.noConflict();` directly after including the jQuery library onto your page. This is because some libraries also attempt to use the `$` sign and clash with jQuery. This hands it back to them on the global scope.

You can still use `$` in your jQuery code by ensuring it is solely within the function's scope (so it doesn't affect other libraries) by `(function($){ ... })(jQuery)`.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   ... Your jQuery code here
}
```

**Edit:** The same behaviour can occur when you include jQuery multiple times onto the same page (as was the OP's case).

Comment: Hi mate, isnt that what i did in the second lot of code in my OP? I have i got it mixed up somewhere?

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Yes, I assumed it would work after you fixed the include url. Check your browser's console and see if there are any errors in there.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. It is just the fact that the top slideshow which is jQuery controlled doesnt show up when this contact form is on the page.

Comment: Just looked at the console. This is the error::Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slideshow' widgetkit-97409d95.js:15

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Do you have a live page I can visit and inspect?

Comment: Sent you a message through your website

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Recieved... you are loading jQuery twice on the page. Remove your include as widgetkit already includes it on the page for you.

Comment: Genius - thanks bud. Ill tick the answer if you wanna update it and just add that little bit in

Comment: Hi mate - got another issue which may be related to the original - ill move it to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30180/discussion-between-dr-pepper-and-george-reith)